# How to stop the fragment shader from duplicating work

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have a game that uses pixel art. The sprites can be rendered anywhere on the screen so pixels from different sprites may not line up.

In my fragment shader I am performing computations (normal mapping) on the colour values coming from the texture. However, there is a significant inefficiency here.

Since the textures are very low resolution and are being scaled up, a single texel corresponds to many screen pixels. This means that the fragment shader is performing the same computation many times: eg. if a texel corresponds to a 4x4 area of pixels on the screen, we are performing the same computation 16 times. This means that your performance decreases significantly as the rendering resolution increases which makes little sense for a pixel art game.

How can I avoid this duplication? A solution would either run a shader once per texel or would cache fragment shader results so that subsequent pixels that correspond to the same texel can use the cached value.

One solution I have considered is to render the whole scene to a lower resolution texture where 1 texel = 1 pixel and then upscale. However, this doesn't allow the sprites to exist at arbitrary locations on the final screen and forces a fixed pixel grid.

Comment: Are you really doing the same computation for each pixel? You are using the exact same light vector, the exact same vector to the camera (for specular hightlights)? If that's the case, you could first render each sprite into a separate framebuffer with 1pixel = 1texel resolution, then upscale that when combining the sprites. But unless you do a very heavy computation in the fragment shader, I'd expect a worse performance than when you do the same calculation multiple times.

Comment: Yes it's the exact same. You are right that the framebuffer swaps would likely give worse performance. I have considered rendering all sprites into a new texture atlas with the computations performed and then rendering from that.

Comment: @KangarooChief: That would have the same problem BDL pointed out: it requires stalling the GPU to wait for it to render to that "new texture atlas with the computations performed". Is what you describe an *actual* performance problem (ie: are you unable to hold framerate specifically because of this), or is this all hypothetical?

Comment: You do need to stall to do 2 render cycles but you don't need to switch out framebuffer s constantly. Two renders per frame should be fine. The main issue would be mapping processed textures all into a new texture atlas. This problem is hypothetical, however I know that I wont be able to do what I want if I need to compute for every screen pixel which is why I chose to use low resolution pixel art.